# CSS: Properly align the edge of Section with Header and Footer

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to CSS and as part of practise trying to implement a simple layout. The layout is complete except for one problem, the right edge of "Section" is not properly aligned with the right edges of "Header" and "Footer". Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?
I understand this can happen due to unnecessary margins but in my case there are no such extra margins.

Screenshot is attached for reference.
[image: Layout]

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Project-1: Simple Layout</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            *{
                border-style: hidden;
                border-width: 1px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body{
                background-color: #2473f2;
                margin-right: 10%;
                margin-left: 10%;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            header, nav, section, footer{
                border-style: solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            nav, section,footer{
                float: left;
            }
            nav, section{
                padding: 300px 0px;
            }
            nav{
                width: 200px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
            section{
                width: 1300px;
            }
            header, footer{
                padding: 20px;
            }
            header{
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            footer{
                margin-top: 20px;
                width: 1540px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Project-1: Simple Layout</h1>
        <div>
            <header>
                HEADER
            </header>
            <nav>
                NAV
            </nav>
            <section>
                SECTION
            </section>
            <footer>
                FOOTER
            </footer>         
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because the `width` of the section is hardcoded. In your case, it has a length of `1300px` But navigation and footer have a width of `100%`.

Comment: Nowdays, grid or flex is used for a mainlayout

Comment: And yeah. As @G-Cyrillus said. I highly recommend using flexboxes. Here's an example for you of how you can achieve that. https://codepen.io/enucar/pen/rNwjJJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various approaches to do so.

1. `Calc()`
2. `Flex Box` `(CSS3)`
3. `Grid System` `(CSS3)`

I wrote you the correct form **[ Flex Box ]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Project-1: Simple Layout</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>
            * {
                border-style: hidden;
                border-width: 1px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #2473f2;
                margin-right: 10%;
                margin-left: 10%;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            header,
            nav,
            section,
            footer {
                border-style: solid;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            nav,
            section,
            footer {
                float: left;
            }
            nav,
            section {
                padding: 300px 0px;
            }
            nav {
                width: 200px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
            section {
                width: 1300px;
            }
            header,
            footer {
                padding: 20px;
            }
            header {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            footer {
                margin-top: 20px;
                width: 1540px;
            }
            /* just added */
            .main-body {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Project-1: Simple Layout</h1>
        <div>
            <header>
                HEADER
            </header>
            <main class="main-body">
                <nav>
                    NAV
                </nav>
                <section>
                    SECTION
                </section>
            </main>
            <footer>
                FOOTER
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you to use fixed pixel values.

In your case the space is there, because the width of your header and footer is 1540px.

The nav has a width of 200px + a margin of 20px. The section a width of 1300px. In total it's only 1520px. Change the width of your section to 1320px and the space should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Float is now not a need anymore, grid and flex are widely implemented and made for this kind of job

- flex example (that can turn into a single column without mediaquerie

```css
* {
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2473f2;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

header,
nav,
section,
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

header,
footer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

nav {
  min-width: 200px;
}

section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
  /*demo purpose */
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

header {}

footer {}
```

```html
<h1>Project-1: Simple Layout</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>
  <nav>
    NAV
  </nav>
  <section>
    SECTION
  </section>
  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

- grid example , it will require a mediaquerie to reset into a single column if needed.

```css
* {
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2473f2;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}

header,
nav,
section,
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

header,
footer {
  grid-column:1 / span 2
}

section {
  min-height: 200px;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

header {}

footer {}
```

```html
<h1>Project-1: Simple Layout</h1>
<div class="flex">
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>
  <nav>
    NAV
  </nav>
  <section>
    SECTION
  </section>
  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

If you really want to use float and loose the benefits of a grid layout , then calc() can help to size your section.

```css
* {
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2473f2;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header,
nav,
section,
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav,
section,
footer {
  float: left;
}

nav,
section {
  padding: 300px 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

section {
  width: calc( 100% - 220px ) ;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 20px; 
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Project-1: Simple Layout</h1>
<div>
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>
  <nav>
    NAV
  </nav>
  <section>
    SECTION
  </section>
  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```